# Binomial test p-value matches Bayesian posterior probability

Tags: bayesian, binomial-distribution, frequentist

I recently observed, for the binomial distribution, an equivalence between the frequentist significance level and the Bayesian posterior probability, as I describe below.

I would like to know if this is part of a more general pattern that applies to a larger class of distributions and tests, and whether this has any bearing on the choice of Bayesian prior, and on the relationship between frequentist probability and Bayesian probability.

Let $p$ be the Binomial probability parameter, $k$ the number of observed successes, $n$ the number of trials.

The p-value of the binomial test for the null hypothesis $p < p_0$ is:
$$
\alpha = \sum_{l = 0}^{k} \binom{n}{l}p_0^l(1-p_0)^{n-l} = 1 - I_{p_0}(k + 1, n - k)\,,
$$
where $I_q(\alpha, \beta)$ is the incomplete regularized beta function.

If I assume $\mathrm{Beta}(1, 0)$ as the Bayesian prior for $p$, the posterior distribution is $\mathrm{Beta}(k + 1, n - k)$, and the posterior probability that $p > p_0$ is:
$$
\mathrm{Prob}[p > p_0] = 1 - I_{p_0}(k + 1, n - k)\,,
$$
i.e. it matches the p-value of the frequentist test.

Comment: Yes, this happens in other cases too.  Note that your $\mathrm{Beta}(1, 0)$ prior is asymmetric and needed here because of your one-sided test; it would not be a natural Bayesian choice of an uninformative prior.  If your loss function is asymmetric, you should use that explicitly in an Bayesian decision rather than distorting the prior

Comment: A paper on this: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00031305.2020.1717621

Comment: The same thing happens for the normal distribution (with known variance), and more generally in the large sample limit ($n \to \infty$) for tests based on the maximum likelihood estimator, since the posterior distribution and the sampling distribution of the MLE converge to the same thing , see (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein-von_Mises_theorem)

Comment: @ChristianHennig thanks. I think the paper only shows large-sample asymptotic equivalence, which does not surprise me as much as the exact equality above.

Comment: @Henry Yes I agree that it's not a natural prior, yet it is striking that it matches the p-value exactly for all values of $k$. A similar equivalence appears to hold for the hypergeometric distribution, so this seems a fairly general thing.